# Calling variable as function() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm having a trouble on how to call the variable as a function. I already research it but it seems it's not working on my code. Any idea whats wrong on my code? Thanks.

First the `HTML`

```
<a class="showhide" id="SampleID"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

Then the `script`

```
// Function for collapse hpanel
$('.showhide').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("id").toString();
    //console.log("ShowHide: " + id);

    setTimeout(function () {
        var fn = window[id];
        fn();
    },200);
});

function SampleID() {
    alert("111");
}
```

But it shows

> Uncaught TypeError: fn is not a function

**Note:** I tried using eval() and its working. But I read that it's not good on using `eval()` that's why I'm trying to find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's working to me

```js
// Function for collapse hpanel
$('.showhide').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var id = $(this).attr("id").toString();
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        var fn = window[id];
        
        fn();
    }, 200);
});

function SampleID() {
    alert("111");
}
```

```css
.showhide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #444444;
  border: 5px solid pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="showhide" id="SampleID"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems that the arrangement of my code causes the error. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine?

```js
// Function for collapse hpanel
$('.showhide').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("id").toString();
    //console.log("ShowHide: " + id);

    setTimeout(function () {
        var fn = window[id];
        fn();
    },200);
});

function SampleID() {
    alert("111");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="showhide" id="SampleID"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">TEST</i></a>
```

I would suggest using the [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) method for defining JavaScript information in the DOM:

```js
var showHideFunctions = [{
  id: "sample-id",
  func: function() {
    console.log("Sample function fired");
  }
}];

function showHideClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-function-id");
  console.log("ShowHide: " + id);
  setTimeout(function() {
    showHideFunctions.find(function(entry) {
      return id == entry.id;
    }).func();
  }, 200);
}
document.querySelectorAll(".showhide")
  .forEach(function(elm) {
    elm.addEventListener("click", showHideClick);
  });
```

```html
<p class="showhide" data-function-id="sample-id">Test</p>
```